# Launch new EC2 instance using shared private AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-ec2

I have a website running on `t2.micro ec2 server (A)`. While it is running I created its AMI and shared it with another AWS account `B`.

I went to the `B` AWS account and tried to launch an EC2 instance with the same configuration (t2 micro). After server B started running. I tried to launch the IP address in the browser, expecting to see the website launched on the new server. But it didn't.

My expectation is that website will be seen on both servers' IPs. Later I will make a copy of AMI, set up Route53, and then turn off the original one and set up Route53 on the second.

But Why is B server not launching the website? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do your basic connectivity checks - internet gateway, public IP, security group, NACL, routing, etc. Launch another instance in the same VPC and use curl / wget / ping to test it. Once you've done that please edit your question to say what you've and we can try to help more.

Comment: Which server are you running? Is it Apache or something else?

Comment: @Tim it worked. I was doing a silly mistake. I wasn't selecting the checkboxes `Allow HTTPs traffic from the internet` and `Allow HTTP traffic from the internet`, and when you wrote check ping test. It clicked and then I was able to fix the problem.

Comment: Great :) Suggest you answer your own question when you can so that the question is marked answered.